# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_mssql.dll

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Yesterday I reinstalled my windows and after installed Apache and copied PHP from dir.
And now I can not get access to PDO MS SQL Server.

In my `php.ini` **`;`** is absent:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

and in D:\Program Files\PHP\ext dll files is exsist.

When I call PDO script from browser I have this error: **could not find driver**.
In Apache error.log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\\Program Files\\PHP\\ext\\php_mssql.dll' - \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe
0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\\Program Files\\PHP\\ext\\php_pdo_mssql.dll' - \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xe
a\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I fix this? 
Thanks.