# PHP Warning PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

- OS:     Windows 8.1
- Arch:   x64
- php:    PHP 7.1.6
- mssql: Mssql Server 2014 express
- driver: SQLSRV 4.0
- IDE: PhpStorm

I'm trying to get mssql drivers to work. 
I downloaded the pdo driver from microsoft, put the file `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll` into `C:\Program Files\PHP\ext` and edited `php.ini` to add `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll` to it.

This is the result:

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.1.6 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2017 01:53:41) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Probable duplicate of this:
[PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_mssql.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993762/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-pdo-mssql-dll)

But that one's never answered and four years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to look at the release information.
That way you can see what version it supports.

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

In my case the mssql driver is still one minor version behind php's latest stable version, so I have to downgrade my php from 7.1 to 7.0.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this error (but with a different DLL version) was caused by adding the wrong PHP SQL SLQSRV DLL to my PHP extensions:

I am using PHP 7.2.21 from XAMPP.

I added these DLLs (included in SQLSRV561.exe):

- php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x86.dll

I enabled `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll` as PHP extension, but the **nts** dll version was the wrong one for my PHP version. When I enabled the **ts** dll version, the error disappeared. ( I am using IIS.)

> Thread Safe (TS) and Non-Thread Safe (NTS) are the two different PHP
>   builds available.

Comment: You should use NTS if you're using IIS

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP version thread-safe? You are using the library for this version, you can use `"php -i|find "Thread"` from command line in windows.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that thread-safe was the default option, but looked again and it's only for when using Apache. That helps a lot, but that didn't solve my issue.

Comment: After questioning, it looks like I need thread-safe after all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using PHP732 on windows server 2019 with IIS10 using the php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll, works just fine without issue. It gives warning if I enable 73_ts_x64.